# RegEx string between N and (N+1)th Occurance

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to find nth occurrence of sub string between two special characters. For example.
one|two|three|four|five

Say, I am looking to find string between (n and n+1 th) 2nd and 3rd Occurrence of '|' character, which turns out to be 'three'.I want to do it using RegEx. Could someone guide me ?

My Current Attempt is as follows.

```
        string subtext = "zero|one|two|three|four";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"(?:([^|]*)|){3}");
        var m = r.Match(subtext).Value;
```

Comment: Why regex and not `s.Split('|').ElementAtOrDefault(2)`?

Comment: Can you not .Split & use the index?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to do it in RegEx, which is why i chose to avoid Split. Following is my current attempt.

            var ggg = Regex.Match(Parsed[0], @"(?:([^|]*)|){4}").Groups;
            string subtext = "zero|one|two|three|four";
            Regex r = new Regex(@"(?:([^|]*)|){3}");
            
            var m = r.Match(subtext).Value;

Comment: I have added the code in original post.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer may skip the nth match to nth+1 (in case of consequent `|`). See my answer for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:
`(?:.*?\|){n}(.[^|]*)`

where `n` is the number of times you need to skip your special character. The first capturing group will contain the result.

[Demo for n = 2](https://regex101.com/r/RmPqxN/1)

Answer (score 4):

If you have full access to C# code, you should consider a mere splitting approach:

```
var idx = 2; // Might be user-defined
var subtext = "zero|one|two|three|four";
var result = subtext.Split('|').ElementAtOrDefault(idx);
Console.WriteLine(result);
// => two
```

A regex can be used if you have no access to code (if you use some tool that is powered with .NET regex):

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){2}([^|]*)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%7C%5D*%5C%7C%29%7B2%7D%28%5B%5E%7C%5D*%29&i=zero%7Cone%7Ctwo%7Cthree%7Cfour). It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^|]*\|){2}`  - 2 (or adjust it as you need) or more sequences of:

  - `[^|]*` - zero or more chars other than `|`
  - `\|` - a `|` symbol
- `([^|]*)` - Group 1 (access via `.Groups[1]`): zero or more chars other than `|`

C# code to test:

```
var pat = $@"^(?:[^|]*\|){{{idx}}}([^|]*)";
var m = Regex.Match(subtext, pat);
if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
// => two
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/UinegV)

If a tool does not let you access *captured groups*, turn the initial part into a non-consuming lookbehind pattern:

```
(?<=^(?:[^|]*\|){2})[^|]*
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%7C%5D*%5C%7C%29%7B2%7D%29%5B%5E%7C%5D*&i=zero%7Cone%7Ctwo%7Cthree%7Cfour). The `(?<=...)` positive lookbehind only checks for a pattern presence immediately to the left of the current location, and if the pattern is not matched, the match will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex and then select the n-th match (in this case `2`) from the `Matches` collection:

```
string subtext = "zero|one|two|three|four";
Regex r = new Regex("(?<=\|)[^\|]*");
var m = r.Matches(subtext)[2];
```

Comment: Hi, actually that would force me to use index. I want to do away with that, and instead use the index within the RegEx. That's one of the reason I didnt use Split